# How to animate active state on hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was wondering how I can achieve the following effect.
I created a header like this:

[image]

What I want is, when you hover over a list item, the red border bottom will be animate to that section, so the red border under "playlist" will be slide for example to "channels", when I hover over "channels". The active state is `active-tab` How can I achieve this?

Live preview: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWMXNL

Comment: You can change the css left property of red bottom with jquery `animate ()` method with 500 ms time interval on hover of each menu.

Comment: You need JS for this.

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this 6 years ago early in my carrer...
Back then I used a plugin called magic line

https://css-tricks.com/jquery-magicline-navigation/

Demo [here](https://css-tricks.com/examples/MagicLine/)

This is a small unminified js script, so you should be able to modify it to meet your exact requirements and paste it into your own js file